# What is the name of a function that takes no argument and returns nothing?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java8

In Java 8's `java.util.function` package, we have:

- **Function**: Takes one argument, produces one result.
- **Consumer**: Takes one argument, produces nothing.
- **Supplier**: Takes no argument, produces one result.
- **...**: Other cases handling primitives, 2 arguments, etc...

But I need to handle the "**takes no argument, produces nothing**" case. There is nothing for this in `java.util.function`.

So, the question is: **What is the name of '*a function that takes no argument and returns nothing*'?**

In Java 8, its definition would be:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface InsertANameHere {
    void execute();
}
```

[Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) already exists and has another purpose : "*An object that executes submitted Runnable tasks*". The signature doesn't match (`execute(Runnable):void`) and is not even a [functional interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html).

[Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) exists, but it is strongly linked to the threading context:

- The package is `java.lang`, not `java.util.function`.
- The Javadoc states : "*The Runnable interface should be implemented by any class whose instances are intended to be executed by a thread*".
- The name "Runnable" suggest some running code inside a thread.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology

Comment: That is not a function.

Comment: Why is this not a function ? [FunctionalInterface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) doesn't forbid it (and it compiles and run fine). Mathematically speaking it is called an empty function for the empty set [Empty function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_function).

Comment: *"But there is nothing for "Takes no argument, produces nothing.""* - [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html)?

Comment: I +1'd your comment even if _"The Runnable interface should be implemented by any class whose instances are intended to be **executed by a thread**"_ which is not my case.

Comment: I think that the javadoc for `Runnable` is outdated at this point, because a Runnable is also used by other classes than `Thread`(`Executor` for example).

Comment: @superbob That doesn't mean that `Runnable`s can only be `.run()` by `Thread`s. In fact they're very commonly used for exactly the purpose described in the question

Comment: @superbob That was it's initial purpose, but since Java 8 it was "retrofitted" as functional interface. So this is why you found nothing in `java.util.function ` package.

Comment: @user11153, I'm considering using Runnable, I will edit my question to mention this

Comment: Semi-Snark: ImpureFuntion because it surely relies only on side effects, otherwise it is a no-op. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function#Impure_functions) More Seriosuly: Imperative (do something), which would at least match the semantics of void execute();

Comment: Well, what I learned in my intro to programming course (on tests) is that it should be called `mystery` to tell any future reader that they have no possible hope of understanding it. Isn't this just a procedure/behavior though?

Comment: RxJava has an `Action0` interface (among many other functional reactive programming niceties) that could be used for this purpose. Of course it's not worth to add a big library for this purpose, but if you are already using RxJava, the `Action0` name makes less confusion about threading.

Comment: Ugh! Those JavaDocs are **missing the main point:** Those names have to do with the _roles_ of the methods within a pipeline: to transform a value, to produce a value, or to consume a value. They are not names for method arity. E.g. not every method that takes one argument and produces nothing acts as a "Consumer." There is no role in a pipeline for a method that takes no argument and returns nothing. There are such roles elsewhere, e.g. within a task queue.

Comment: FWIW Java 11 standard library uses a `Runnable` for this purpose in at least one place: [`Optional::ifPresentOrElse​(Consumer<? super T> action, Runnable emptyAction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresentOrElse(java.util.function.Consumer,java.lang.Runnable)) (Which admittedly also made me think at first if it would run on a different thread)

Comment: You could use `Consumer<Void>` as your type. You can instantiate one with `unused -> someVoidAction()`, and always pass `null` in place of `unused`.

Comment: *"A function that takes no argument and returns nothing"*? I'd like to suggest the term *whitespace*. I've turned to using the word "method" to generically describe a named block of instructions, which may or may not take any arguments or return any values. Categorising methods as suppliers and consumers etc. is almost certain to lead to woe, because either you have to accept that the niladic function with no return values is of no computational effect at all, or you have to acknowledge the existence of "side effects" which invalidates the categories of "supplier" and "consumer". (1/2)

Comment: Because you can easily have suppliers and consumers with "side effects" too (i.e. access to context in a way that doesn't correspond with, and can't be explained by, the functional paradigm), as well as those without such effects (i.e. "pure" functions). So there's at least 8 categories, based on whether they are pure or contextual, and whether they supply, consume, transform, or have no inline effect, and that's before attempting to categorise the contextual effects in a similar manner as the inline effects. (2/2)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Java's choice to do it that way with a separate name for every arity was not exactly worth emulating.  However, if you *must* for the sake of consistency, or if you're writing very generic library code, Konrad's suggestions are good.  I might throw `Procedure` into the ring.

Using a pseudo-functional paradigm doesn't mean normal naming principles should go out the window.  Interfaces should almost always be named after what they *do*, not after some generic syntactic idea.  If the functions are placed into an undo stack, they should be named `UndoFunction`.  If they are called from GUI events, they should be named `GUIEventHandler`.

Comment: `Procedure` is fine too. For the context, I'm developing a generic library that needs to handle this kind of "structure".

Comment: I like `Procedure` from my pascal days. A `Procedure` has side effects, a `Function` does not. Since you don't return a value, the only thing it could do is have a side effect.

Comment: I might be inclined to use `ProcedureRIR<T1,T2>` for `void proc(T1, int, T2)`, and likewise for other types--probably creating most of them on demand rather than trying to cram in every possible combination of types.

Comment: Indeed, **real** functional programming generally don't encourage Hungarian style naming. This is more the mentality of the oo paradigm rather than functional.

Comment: `If the functions are placed into an undo stack, they should be named UndoFunction.` There's a difference between naming the function and giving it a different type though. In functional style you wouldn't create an `UndoFuncton` type because now you can't pass it to `flip`, `curry`, `compose`, `filter`, `map`, etc. In my opinion *that* is the real reason Java's decision to give functions with different arities different names is stupid. Of course, if you're going to use side effects, call it whatever; you already threw composition out the window and you're arguably not using functions either.

Comment: Generic function names make sense in Java 8 with lambdas. Let's say I come across the method  `getUsername(Consumer<String> onUsername)`. I immediately know the signature of the argument, and the name of the argument tells me what it does. If it were called `getUsername(UsernameCallback callback)`, I would know what it does, but I would have to look up the signature of `UsernameCallback`. And since lambdas are unnamed anyway, my code will be the same either way, so the former is better in my view.

Comment: Names like `Consumer<String>` are better than `UsernameCallback`, but still not as good as specifying a simple signature like `String => Unit`.

Answer (score 49):

In the java world, it is called `Runnable`.  In the C# world, it is called `Action`.

But, there is a better name which nicely fits within a larger view of things.

The larger view of things comes later, when you decide that besides the functional interface with a parameterless void method you also need another interface with a parameterless method that returns a generic value; and once you have those two, I guarantee to you that you will need additional versions of each, accepting one, two, or more generic arguments. When that happens, you will want the names of all those interfaces to be isomorphic and correspondent with each other.

So, in Java I have my own set of functional interfaces that I call `Procedure`s, defined as follows:

```
public interface Procedure
{
    void invoke();
}

public interface Procedure1<T1>
{
    void invoke( T1 argument1 );
}

public interface Procedure2<T1>
{
    void invoke( T1 argument1, T2 argument2 );
}
```

... (you get the picture.)

And I also have a similar set of interfaces called `Function`s, defined in a similar way, with the first generic parameter being the return type:

```
public interface Function<R>
{
    R invoke();
}

public interface Function1<R,T1>
{
    R invoke( T1 argument1 );
}

public interface Function2<R,T1,T2>
{
    R invoke( T1 argument1, T2 argument2 );
}
```

... (similar picture.)

(C# already does exactly that with `Func` and `Action`. The names they have chosen are not ideal, but they are not bad enough to warrant replacing them with my preferred names.)

So, my point here is that `Procedure` is a very good name because it nicely fits within a larger view of things, and this is something that you will inevitably run into.

***NOTE:*** I basically ***do agree*** with Karl Bielefeldt's assertion that "normal naming principles should [not] go out the window" and that "Interfaces should almost always be named after what they do, not after some generic syntactic idea."  But note that even he allows for "almost always".  Sometimes there is a need for (essentially anonymous) procedures and functions, and that's what the OP is asking, and that's what I am answering.

**Amendment 2017-11-10:**

You might ask, why `Function1<R,T1>` instead of `Function1<T1,R>`? It could go either way, but I have a preference for return values on the left because I like to follow the 'convert-from' (destination-from-source) naming convention as opposed to the 'convert-to' (source-to-destination) convention.  (Which is more of an accident than a convention, really, in the sense that most probably, nobody ever gave it any thought, because if they had given it any thought at all they would have arrived at the 'convert-from' convention.)

You can read about this in [Joel Spolksy - Making Wrong Code Look Wrong](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/).

It is a very long article, which I recommend reading in its entirety, but if you want to jump straight to the case at hand, search for 'TypeFromType'.

To give you the TL;DR, the idea is that the following:

```
myint = intFromStr( mystr )
```

is much better than the following:

```
myint = strToInt( mystr )
```

because in the first case the names of the types are close to the associated values, so you can easily see that the 'int' matches with the 'int' and the 'str' matches with the 'str'.

So, by extension, I tend to order things in the way they are going to appear in code.

Comment: This solution is really good, it seems even more bulletproof than java's own Supplier, Consumer, BiFunction, ..., because it lays everything down to two concepts only. It reminds me of @Karl Bielefeldt answer about "_Java's choice to do it that way with a separate name for every arity [that] was stupid_". The only "downside" being that it doesn't handle primitive types  and their combinations (fun stuff like DoubleToLongFunction, ToLongBiFunction, ...). But primitives is another concern ...

Comment: Yes.  Basically, once you start replacing generics with primitives, this means that you ***really*** care about performance, so it is okay if you deviate from the convention presented here and use highly customized names for a highly custom performance improvement.

Comment: If I could accept a 2nd answer, I would choose yours thanks to the Procedure _N_, Function _N_ suggestions. I still upvoted it.

Comment: Why is it not `Function1<T1, R>`?

Comment: @ErikE that's a very good question, and I amended my post to answer it.

Comment: Mike, I am familiar with that article and have named things so for years, too—makes so much sense. Despite that, I think it best to follow the convention established by both Java and C# of putting the return value type argument last in generics... the risk of confusing developers is higher when there’s a clearly established convention being broken. While we can all be sad they didn’t do it the other way, I recommend all readers to consider very carefully if breaking the convention is good for your code base.

Comment: @ErikE yes, sure, there are reasons for not doing it my way, that's why I wrote "it can go either way".  Personally, I am a bit weary of the philosophical question of whether "convention" is another word for "progress-stopper" in certain areas.

Answer (score 19):

Why not `Command`? Given that it takes no data and returns no data, but assuming that calling it causes some effect (otherwise it would be rather pointless really), I imagine that's roughly the only thing it can do - fire an action, make something happen.

Speaking of which, there's also a generic `Action` delegate in .NET. Unlike Java's `Consumer` it can take from 0 to 16 arguments; in other words, the simpliest version of it takes none - see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

And since the name doesn't imply there's anything to "consume", it also seems like a good name choice.

Comment: `Command` is good. It can be confused with the [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) but it might be the solution.

Comment: I do like `Action` more than `Command`. A command sounds more like something that is received and evaluated, while an action is executed for its side effects.

Comment: Umm... how can it *not* be a Command pattern? You have built exactly the Command entity! It even has traditionally-named `execute()` method. 0_o'

Comment: Dislike suggestion of Action, as that is a common (and good) Swing interface.  Command is reasonable.

Comment: @user949300 but it depends on the context - Java is a big world you see, I'm an Android developer (now) and I have no J2EE-related idiosyncrasies ;) I agree, of course, that chosen naming convention shouldn't clash with the one your framework uses.